# How can I restore a Windows 8 laptop which hangs during startup recovery?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have an ASUS laptop running Windows 8 which is about 6 months old. It will power up; however, Windows tries tries to repair itself during startup and the process never completes. It gets stuck on a blank bluish screen – nothing else on it, just the color. How would I fix this issue? Would a factory reset help, and if so how would I do it? Or is the hard drive compromised?

Microsoft recommends using the advanced troubleshooting options to initiate a factory reset, but because the boot repair hangs, I can't get as far as that option.

Comment: @pulsarjune that was not a quality edit. The post needs a lot of work and you just added one tag which isn't even relevant. If you read the post you'll see it says "a bluish blank screen", which is different from [tag:BSOD] which is an error message screen. Please work on making better edits.

Comment: Could you specify the model of the laptop? When you boot up and it "tries to repair itself" what does it say exactly? I'm assuming it's _not_ an issue with the screen itself being broken if you can see some sort of "repairing" message during startup?

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me once, some files got corrupted in some way.

If you have a CD boot the windows from the cd , if not create a bootable usb which you add windows 8 on it and you'll have an option to format or to repair damaged error.

Answer (score 0):

ASUS has [instructions on their website](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008226/) for resetting to the factory defaults. 
During the "attempting repairs" steps that you mentioned seeing, you should arrive at a prompt where you can click "Advanced Options". From that menu, click "Troubleshoot" and then "Reset your PC". This should reset your computer to factory defaults. Note that you *will* lose any files currently saved on the computer if you do this.

Edit: Based on your comments, it sounds like the normal system recovery mechanism isn't working. You'll want to create a system repair drive, which should allow you to start the PC reset process. You need a USB flash drive and a separate computer running the same version of Windows 8 or 8.1 as you are.

- On the working computer, type "recovery drive" into the start screen's search, and open "create a recovery drive".

  [image: type "recovery drive" into the start menu]
- The recovery media creator will open. *Uncheck* "copy the recovery partition to the recovery drive" if it's an option.

  [image: Recovery Drive options]
- Click Next. A list of plugged in flash drives will be displayed. Select the flash drive you want to use to create the recovery media. Anything on the drive will be deleted.

  [image: Recovery Drive select flash drive]
- On the next screen, verify you selected the right drive, and click "Create". The recovery drive will then be created on the flash drive. When it's finished, eject the flash drive and plug it in to the disabled PC.
- On the disabled PC, boot to the flash drive. The exact key to start USB boot is different for each computer. Refer to [this guide](https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive) to find the right key for your computer. It appears that for newer ASUS computers like yours, you would probably press Esc.
- Boot to the flash drive. In the recovery options you should be able to select Troubleshooting and then Reset PC. This will reset the computer to its default settings.

Comment: it doesn't get to that advanced options screen..

Comment: @RandytBaker so it's going through the "repairing" screens and then it gets stuck on a blank screen with nothing showing?

Comment: that's correct. That's all it does.

Comment: What version of Windows is it? And does the computer have a CD/DVD drive, or do you have a spare flash drive around?

Comment: win8 no cd drive. its empty 500g hard drive

Comment: might ave flash drive not sure have to check.h

Comment: it DOES however have an external cd

Comment: Flash drive is better. You're going to need a flash drive (at least 256 MB) and a separate PC with the same version of Windows 8 or 8.1. I'll edit my answer to have instructions.

Comment: have laptop secondary with same os.

Comment: @RandytBaker OK I've added detailed instructions, give that a try. Hope it helps!

Comment: where is it you said?

Comment: @RandytBaker you may need to refresh the page; I edited the answer I posted.